# 08 chevy suburban 1500 passenger airbag light is on and said it is disabled

Tags: chevrolet, cel, supplemental-restraint-system, suburban

I hav e a 2008 chevy suburban 1500 . The passenger airbag light is on and said is disabled, i have notice a wire  like a usb connector cable that is hanging out of the glove compartment but i can not see where it is suposed to get connected. I am almost positive that this  wire has to do with the airbag problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to tell what is going on with the airbag system is to get a reader which will talk to the Supplemental Restraint System (SRS) through the OBDII port. Then you'll know for sure what's going on. If the wire which is hanging out does not have a yellow connector, odds are, this is not your SRS problem. More than likely, one of the two front impact sensors is bad. This is a very common issue on the GM trucks (I know, I have one). They are very easy to change out as it's only one bolt & one connector and they are located off of the bottom of the radiator support. Very easy to get to. However, you still need to know if this is your issue before you start changing out parts. Get a reader, or find someone who has one which will read SRS codes (not all OBDII readers will) and figure out exactly what is going on.